# Time series pair X, Y, with first half correlation 0.3 and rest half 0.4, what is the general correlation?

Tags: correlation

As is stated by the title
Time series pair X, Y, with first half correlation 0.3 and rest half 0.4, what is the general correlation?

Comment: @Quantuple, what's missing to get the result?

Comment: Seems to have a duplicate on Cross Validated here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15026/7469

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too weak for migration and possibly duplicated.